# Update existing documents in a MongoDB collection using mongoimport

Tags: mongodb, csv, upsert, mongoimport

I am trying to update specific documents in a collection using mongoimport. I have created a csv file which contains two columns: "email" and "contactInfo.mobileNumber".

CSV strutcture:

```
email,contactInfo.mobileNumber
test123@gmail.com,9892345109
```

Objective: Update the "mobileNumber" of matching document using email as the key/query parameter(email should uniquely identify the document).

The "mobileNumber" is a string stored inside a set called "contactInfo". So "contactInfo" is a part of the document structure.
Structure of "contactInfo" is as follows. It contains multiple objects of the following type:

```
contactInfo
    _id
    homeNumber
    mobileNumber
```

I tried the following mongoimport commands:

```
1.  mongoimport --host --db --collection --mode upsert --headerline --file --type=csv
2. mongoimport --host --db --collection --mode merge --headerline --file--type=csv
3.  mongoimport --host --db --collection --upsertFields email --headerline --file --type=csv
```

However the above commands always create a new document instead of updating an existing document. It creates a new document with three fields (`_id`, `homeNumber` and `mobileNumber` which is nested under contactInfo).

How do I update the documents in the db which match the email in `.csv` file?